# NodeJS Async Await Insert Data to Database and Google API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, google-sheets-api

I'm working as API Backend with NodeJS. In case, when I insert 1 row the data will automatically updated to DB and Goolge Sheet API.

I already create the code in controller but I want to make it as Async Await, to makesure data inserted to DB first.

Here is my code:

```html
createUser: (req, res, next) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(Number(env.SALTROUNDS_USER), (err, resultSalt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, resultSalt, (err, hash) => {
        doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function(err){
          // regis to db
          let datauser = new modelsUsers({
            email: req.body.email,
            name: req.body.name,
            password: hash,
            phone_number: req.body.phone_number
          });
          //regis to GoogleSheetApi
          doc.addRow(1,{
            timestamps: tgl_ob,
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone_number: req.body.phone_number
          },function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err); //errors
            }
          });
            if(err){
              console.log(err); //success
            }
          datauser.save((err, result) => {
            if (result) res.send(result);
            else res.send(err);
          });
        })
      });
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) to make callbacks to promise

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util')
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(process.env.sheetid);
const creds = require('./../creds.json') // JSON file you can get from serviceaccount

createUser: (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(Number(env.SALTROUNDS_USER), (err, resultSalt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, resultSalt, async (err, hash) => {
      // you can also convert genSalt, salt to Promis
      await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds)
      const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
      const sheets = info.worksheets;
      let datauser = new modelsUsers({
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        password: hash,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number
      });
      const data = {
        timestamps: tgl_ob,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number
      }
      // as you need to save to DB first and then add ROW to sheet
      datauser.save(async (err, result) => {
        if (result) {
          await addRows(sheets, 1, data) // you can wrap in try catch for error handling
          res.send(result);
        }
        else res.send(err);
      });

      })
    });
}

function addRows(sheet, index, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sheet[index].addRow(data, (err, row) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(row)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: got an error with await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds). cause await is only valid in async function

Comment: please make sure your upper scope in asyc

Comment: const Users = require("../controllers/user");
router.post("/user/create",  Users.createUser);

so i need to set asyc here?

Comment: you need to set async wherever you are using await just before that, i have given you proper working example please check line by line